# Visualising nodes classified in heirarchies and their relationshops

Tags: python, networkx, requirements-management

I am a requirement engineer which has created a dataset which is as follows
Requirement ID, Requirement type (business, user and goal), relationship
a relationship relates a requirement to another. It could be between requirements of different types and requirements of same type. I want to create a visualisation to see how messy these relationships are while also considering the types as levels. Something like this

```
business_req1  business_req2
    |             |
    |             |
user_req 1  user_req2
    |          |
user_req3 -----|
```

how can i do that?

I dived into graph and network analysis but I miss the view of heirarchical levels

Comment: Please can you provide a sample dataset?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.